# Roblox remoteevents change value

Tags: roblox

local script

```
function Click(player)

    if game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 0 then local num = 1
    elseif game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 1 then local num = 0
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Test:FireServer(player ,num)
    
    end         
    script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(Click)

end
```

server script

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
ReplicatedStorage.Test.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player ,num)
    if player:GetRankInGroup(1) > 248 then
        game.Workspace.Folder.Value = num
    else 
        
        end
    end

)
```

Doesn't work at all, tried testing if it even connects by printing stuff.

Comment: Heyo, could you update your question to include some more details? Could you explain what you are trying to do? What isn't working and maybe include the error message as well? It's not enough to say something doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying to make this run when the remote event is fired 

"game.Workspace.Folder.Value = num"

num should be 1 or 0 depending on the "if" statements on the local script
There is no output or error code, value doesn't change either.

Comment: thanks kylaaa, the click detector was a test function to easily run it but the actual function was when a certain message was sent

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of issues.

## 1. LocalScripts only run in a few locations, and the Workspace isn't one of them.

Based on your code, I'm assuming this LocalScript is a child of a ClickDetector in the Workspace.

See the docs for [LocalScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) :

> A LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player’s Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
> - A Player’s character model
> - A Player’s PlayerGui
> - A Player’s PlayerScripts.
> - The ReplicatedFirst service

So you need to move the LocalScript to a location where it will actually run, then update the path to the ClickDetector.

```
-- find the detector in the Workspace
local detector = game.Workspace.Part.ClickDetector
detector.MouseClick:Connect(Click)
```

## 2. The connection is inside a function that never gets called.

This looks like a typo, but the line where the MouseClick signal is connected to happens inside the Click function, not outside. So effectively, the Click function is declared and never called by anything. You need to move it outside the last `end`

## 3. Variables declared using `local` are only accessible at the level (or deeper) that they are declared at.

Let me annotate your code to highlight what's happening...

```
local function Click(player)
    if game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 0 then
        local num = 1
        -- num stops existing here and Test is never fired
    elseif game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 1 then 
        local num = 0
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Test:FireServer(num)
        -- Test is fired with a value of 0 only when Folder.Value equals 1
    end
end

local detector = game.Workspace.Part.ClickDetector
detector.MouseClick:Connect(Click)
```

To fix this, you need to move the `local num` declaration to a higher scope so it is encapsulates the if-statement. Then you need to make sure that the Remote event is fired in both cases, so you should move it outside the if-statement...

```
function Click(player)
    -- define num
    local num
    if game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 0 then 
        num = 1
    else --if game.Workspace.Folder.Value == 1 then
        num = 0
    end

    -- fire the RemoteEvent
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Test:FireServer(num)

end         
local detector = game.Workspace.Part.ClickDetector
detector.MouseClick:Connect(Click)
```

## 4. (Nit-pick) Bad tabbing in your server Script creates confusion

This is not something you need to fix, but as atomfrog pointed out, nothing is happening in your Script's else block. It is unnecessary to have it at all, and it looks like you tried to use `end` to escape from the Script, but all you've done is indented your if-statement incorrectly. If you want to escape or for nothing to happen, use `return`, or don't have an else block.

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
ReplicatedStorage.Test.OnServerEvent:Connect( function(player, num)
    local specialGroupId = 1
    local lowestPermissionLevel = 248

    if player:GetRankInGroup(specialGroupId) > lowestPermissionLevel then
        game.Workspace.Folder.Value = num
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it doesn't work because you have nothing after the `else`

Comment: The else leads to end which stops the script, it should be changing the value due to my rank being lower then 248 and < = " Is less than"